# Flipped NSScrollView problems

Tags: ios, cocoa, uiscrollview, nsscrollview

I have an NSScrollView that needs to display a variable amount of NSViews in it. I made a custom NSView that has isFlipped return YES and put my NSViews in that before I set it to be the NSScrollView's documentView. That works well. It displays my items top to bottom like I would expect.

But, when the contents changes and I need to change the NSScrollView's documentView's frame, my contents disappears.

This would be WAY easier with a UIScrollView, but alas.

I'm assuming these are equivalent:

```
[NSScrollView.documentView setFrame:newFrame];
[UIScrollView setContentSize:newSize];
```

I would imagine that a lot of coders need to have a flipped NSScrollView, but how do you deal with changing the content size without this madness? Obviously, I'm missing something.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: If you are going to use Auto Layout instead, I recorded a video tutorial. Look at my answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49947440/2846508

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the internal views and autoresizing/constraints. My internal views are actually a series of view controllers with their own xib file. In each view controller, I added the following line:

```
[self.view setAutoresizingMask:NSViewNotSizable];
```

And that solved everything.

Special thanks to lead_the_zeppelin for helping me (in chat) go through everything.

Comment: awwww. I was so close :)

Answer (score 0):

can you try just setting

```
[scrollView.documentView setFrameSize:newFrame.size];
```

to see if your content disappears?

Comment: Same thing. It just disappears.

Comment: @pizzafilms where are you setting *setFrameSize*: ?

Comment: I've tried setting it do different places with the same result. At first, I create a large flipped NSView and put my other views in there. Then I set the documentView to my large content view. Then I calculate the actual size of the items and then set the frameSize.

Comment: Interesting...I printed out the frames of the items inside my documentView before changing the frame size (and they were visible) and then printed out the frames after setting the frame size. After, the frames y origin were all negative numbers.

Comment: I create my interior views by creating them with a normal size frame and then, addSubview.

Comment: I just tried it out myself and can't replicate the said behavior. Can you post more code? We will get to the bottom of this!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40485/discussion-between-pizzafilms-and-lead-the-zeppelin)

Comment: did you try setting autoResizeMask on RGFlippedView?