# Embedding Custom View with controls in NSScrollView

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsscrollview

I'm trying to create a scrollable view with multiple controls inside it. For this I'm wrapping a Custom View control inside a `NSScrollView` and set the size of the custom view to about the same as the scroll view.

However if I place other controls inside the custom view in Interface Builder they don't appear in the custom view when running. Why is that?

If I place a button in a Custom View that is not wrapped in a `NSScrollView` it works but I want the custom view to be scrollable in case the window height is too small to show all controls.

Answer (score 0):

After dragging in an NSScrollView in Interface Builder, look at the outline view in the xib window.  You'll see that you now have a Bordered Scroll View, which contains a ClipView, which then contains a NSView.

a.  Make sure your Custom View have been added as a subview to the NSView.  If you add them at a higher level, you wont get the behavior you want.

or

b.  Another option is to simply change the class of the NSView to your custom view class.  Select the View that is inside the BorderedScrollView->ClipView, then click the 3rd tab from left (in the upper right of Xcode window) where you can type in your custom class name in the field labeled "Class".

Comment: Thanks but it's not an issue related to the view hierarchy as this is all set correctly. I think this issue is related to Auto-layout but I haven't yet figured out what's the problem.

Comment: Almost figured it out: The custom view needs to be auto-layout pinned. However I get warnings for inconsistent  auto-layout frames and the custom view is all the way scrolled down. Creating a custom view subclass and return flipped = true obviously doesn't do anything in IB. There must surely be a way to get this set up properly in IB, no?

Comment: I have it mostly solved after reading this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29241474/enabling-nsscrollview-to-scroll-its-contents-using-auto-layout-in-interface-buil ... the ClipView needed to be flipped, not the document view.